# Terraform: AWS Codepipeline architecure to deploy each resource in own pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit, aws-devops

I am using Terraform with AWS CodePipeline and AWS CodeCommit. I plan to keep each resource in its own folder (same repo) and then deploy each resource separately in its own pipeline.

For example, I create a **VPC resource** directory that will have its own pipeline. When I make changes to the files inside that directory and push the update - it will only deploy the VPC resource and not other resources.

Any idea how I might architect that?

Thank you

Comment: How exactly are you planning to manage this when resources need replacement?

Comment: @Marcin not sure what you mean by replacement? Each resource will have its own state file. When you make a modification in the specific directory it will run the respective pipeline and replace the resource.

Comment: Lets say you have instances in your VPC. If you want to modify VPC so that it must be deleted and recreated first, how exactly are you going to deal with the instances there?

Comment: But that would always be the case, isn't it? One could add a new subnet and modify certain VPC configurations but not delete a subnet with deployed instances. What I'm trying to achieve is a more modular approach.